# Codesandbox live preivew

Tags: reactjs, codesandbox, live-preview

I hope someone can help me with this.

I am writing my CSS for React APP in codesandbox but on CTRL + S, I am not able to see live changes, even if I've turned live preview ON.

Someone had same problems?

Cheers!

Comment: how are you importing your css into the app? it could be a configuration thing

Comment: @tachko You've right, I've wrongly imported CSS files.